# Can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm developing my first aspect and I'm encountering the following trouble.

MyAspect class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect{


@Pointcut("execution(* com.mypackage.MyClass.method(..))")
public void sendComunication(){}

@AfterReturning("sendComunication()")
public void sendComunicationMail() {

    //TODO somethings
}
```

}

Then i added "aop:aspectj-autoproxy" and aop namespace in the applicationContext. Now when i try to build my application, i get this error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut sendComunication
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut sendComunication
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:210)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 42 more
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added component scan? I am not sure if that should matter, though.

Comment: Yes, i added component scan

Comment: could you post the trace?

Answer (score 5):

[This post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/581630/Spring/Pointcut-methods) hints that you need to upgrade to a newer version of aspectj. [Get it here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj).

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to find the aspect whatever you have mentioned (   i. e "execution(* com.mypackage.MyClass.method(..))"   ). method signature might be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that

> com.mypackage.MyClass

wasn't a bean managed to Spring, but instead it was a method in vaadin panel

Comment: This wouldn't change anything to the error you got. The `@Aspect` doesn't need to be applied to be created. Failure occurs when Spring tries to create the `@Aspect` but can't find a `@Pointcut` that matches `sendCommunication()`.